# Keep SSH session alive while computer sleep?

Tags: ssh, timeout

Is it possible to keep SSH session alive while computer sleep? When I put my Mac (Lion) to sleep for a short period of time and then wake it up session still alive, but if I leave it overnight session connection is closed.

I've tried set:

```
ClientAliveInterval 3600
ClientAliveCountMax 10
```

same result

Why session "survive" for a short period of time? How can I control this timeout?

Comment: I have a way to make it alive but I need this question to be re-opened. believe me you will love my answer. well my answer is use Wake ON LAN to make your putty alive. Putty only disconnected when it sense that the network card is not connected to the network. Meaning that, even if your computer is sleep, ssh is connected to your client and when u open back your pc putty will resume your connection! You don't have to use any special software for this. Just to make sure that your hardware supports Wake On LAN and you need to enable it.

Comment: Perhaps the question can be moved to [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or [superuser](https://superuser.com) so it can stay open?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer it depends on tcp keepalive settings:

For the list of available TCP settings (FreeBSD 4.8 an up and 5.4):

```
sysctl -A | grep net.inet.tcp
```

- `net.inet.tcp.keepidle` - Amount of time, in milliseconds, that the (TCP) connection must be idle before keepalive probes (if enabled) are sent.
- `net.inet.tcp.keepintvl` - The interval, in milliseconds, between keepalive probes sent to remote machines. After TCPTV_KEEPCNT (default 8) probes are sent, with no response, the (TCP)connection is dropped.
- `net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive` - Assume that SO_KEEPALIVE is set on all TCP connections, the kernel will periodically send a packet to the remote host to verify the connection is still up.

Therefore formula to calculate maximum TCP inactive connection time is following:

```
net.inet.tcp.keepidle + (net.inet.tcp.keepintvl x 8)
```

the result is in milliseconds. Therefore, by setting

```
net.inet.tcp.keepidle = 10000
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl = 5000
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive = 1 (must be 1 always)
```

the system will disconnect a call when TCP connection is dead for: `10000 + (5000 x 8) = 50000` msec (50 sec). To make system remember these settings at startup, you should add them to `/etc/sysctl.conf` file

Comment: Is this to be applied on the server side?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think yes, server side:

[TCP Keepalive](http://jampad.net/Library/tcpipprot/ch17.html):


If the user were to establish the connection, do some work, then just power off the computer at the end of the day, without logging off, a half-open connection would be left. If the client disappears, leaving the half-open connection on the server’s end, and the server is waiting for some data from the client, the server will wait forever. The keepalive feature is intended to detect these half-open connections from the server side.

Comment: is it possible to have a proxy for my sleeping system which could keep sending packets to the server? This way the session could be kept alive even after sleep.

Answer (score 11):

If you want an elegant solution for keeping a remote session alive, you should check the `screen` utitity. When using this utility you can keep your remote programs running even after you logout or shutdown your computer. Then you can reconnect your available `screen` session later.

Screen requires some time to learn the basics, but when you got the handle of it, you will see how powerful it is.

You can check this link for a tutorial on using screen: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/

Comment: Indeed an elegant solution, but not answer my question. Thanks for suggestion, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I prefer the newer [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) alternative.

Comment: http://bphogan.com/2012/06/15/tmux/

Answer (score 7):

Another possible solution is [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu), which isn't exactly SSH but does keep your shell connection alive when your computer goes to sleep, or even after changing IP addresses.

Comment: The problem with `mosh` is that it requires a large range of UDP ports to be opened on the firewall.  This is a problem for a lot of people.

Comment: technically, it's possible to `sshuttle` UDP traffic over ssh session, and then start `mosh`

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use [autossh](http://www.debianadmin.com/autossh-automatically-restart-ssh-sessions-and-tunnels.html), which basically monitors your ssh session and reconnects as soon as it is interrupted (e.g. after a sleep cycle, but also if you lose a WiFi connection for a while, for instance). This works especially well for forwarded ports/ssh tunnels.

Here is a tutorial: http://linuxaria.com/howto/permanent-ssh-tunnels-with-autossh.

Comment: perfect thanks, this does what i thought mosh did. 
super easy, works seamlessly to just prefix my existing ssh command with auto*

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, sessions are closed when no data is transmitted.
Leaving `htop` open usually prevents my ssh connections from closing, as well as providing usefull real-time informations.

Keepalive should do the same thing. You could maybe try to reduce the interval (the delay between two keepalives) to something like 60, see if it changes anything.

Comment: If computer is not sleeping SSH sessions are fine, but I want to re-use same session after it wakes up after sleeping. It works for short sleep time but not for long.

Comment: You probably can't keep the ssh session open during hibernation - keepalive won't be sent if the computer is sleeping. Screen is the way to go : http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/